# Why my apps got deleted - diskspace/memory low?

Tags: applications, memory, disk-space

This sucks - my apps got deleted so when I try to open them, I see this question mark in the icons on the tray. Background apps like docker etc, also are not appearing in the system tray at the top status bar. What the hell happened? My computer was low on memory apparently but I don't see why that would delete files?

[image]

Comment: what machine do you have and what version of the OS are you running?

Comment: the apps shouldn't have been deleted unless your using an iPad.  Maybe the files are still on your machine. Have you looked in your Application Folder to see if Apps are still there?

Comment: Were the apps installed to the Application folder? Or had you left them in Downloads and they got deleted when you did some cleaning up?

Comment: Low in memory or low on disk space?  Go to *About This Mac* and select storage. For memory, open up activity monitor And post a screen shot of what you see